# C++ Template preprocessor tool

Tags: c++, templates, macros, opencl, c-preprocessor

Is there a compiler or standalone preprocessor which takes C++ files and runs a template expansion pass, generating new C++ code with expanded template instantiations?

I remember such a tool in the mid-90s when templates were still new and experimental, and the preprocessor was a way to do template programming with compilers without native template support.

This is a lot more complicated than a macro-processing step since it would likely require parsing and tokenizing the code to understand the contexts.

My hope is to use such a tool when writing OpenCL code.  [OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) is C++, but does not support templates.  I'm hoping I can write templates, even simple ones like with integer or bool only arguments, and have some tool pre-parse the file and go through and find the use of the templates and expand the invocations and give me new C++ code that the OpenCL compiler **can** understand.

Even a very limited tool could be useful, it does not need to support every template quirk, nor even support multiple modules or anything.

The alternative: `#define` macros everywhere.. uglier, unsafe, less efficient, and less versatile.

Comment: OpenCL's language is based on C99 syntax, not C++ according to the page you linked.

Comment: AMD do some extension to openCL, you could develop template codes if you aim for the AMD devices only.It is a pain that we could not use template to develop our algorithms.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Comeau C++](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/) can "compile" C++ to C.  This would seem to be close to your goal, as OpenCL does not support C++ – it's much closer to C.

Comment: Yes! This is the tool I used 15 years ago for the same reason! Excellent, thanks.

Comment: "for the same reason" -- you had OpenCL 15 years ago?  Wow!  ;-)

Comment: Now this site doesn't work, and as I understand Comeau C++ now doesn't developing, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

C++ Insights (https://cppinsights.io/) is able to do this (and more generally expansion of "high-level" syntax-sugary C++ constructs. It is based on Clang so it has an understanding of the code which is as good as possible, and supports latest standards.

It will for instance expand

```
extern "C" void printf(...);
template<typename T>
int foo(T t)
{
  if constexpr(sizeof(T) == 4) {
    printf("int: %d", t);
  }
  else {
    printf("something else: %d", (int)t);
  }
}

int main()
{
    const char arr[10]{2,4,6,8};

    for(const char& c : arr)
    {
      foo(c);
    }
}
```

into

```
extern "C" void printf(...);
template<typename T>
int foo(T t)
{
  if constexpr(sizeof(T) == 4) {
    printf("int: %d", t);
  }
  else {
    printf("something else: %d", (int)t);
  }
}

/* First instantiated from: insights.cpp:19 */
#ifdef INSIGHTS_USE_TEMPLATE
template<>
int foo<char>(char t)
{
  if constexpr(false) {
  } else /* constexpr */ {
    printf("something else: %d", static_cast<int>(t));
  } 
  
}
#endif


int main()
{
  const char arr[10] = {2, 4, 6, 8, '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0'};
  {
    char const (&__range1)[10] = arr;
    const char * __begin1 = __range1;
    const char * __end1 = __range1 + 10L;
    for(; __begin1 != __end1; ++__begin1) {
      const char & c = *__begin1;
      foo(c);
    }
    
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such tool - templates are part of the language, not some pre-processor pass - they are processed by the compiler, just like other code.

Comment: Yes.. such a tool would indeed need to parse the C++. That's why it's more complicated than a macro preprocessor.

Comment: Well, like I say, no such thing exists to my knowledge. I can't see how it could process the templates and leave the "non-template" code untouched.

Comment: @Neil: the very first c++ compilers simply converted c++ code to valid c and compiled it using a c compiler. Certainly this is no longer the case, but used to be fairly usual.

Comment: @Evan I know - I was a user of cfront from the E release onwards. However, the original question said that he wanted to expand the templates but leave the the other C++ code alone, producing a new C++ program, which cfront (and comeau) can't do. It now turns out he wants something different - such is life.

Comment: @Evan Teran: The very first C++ compilers didn't compile C++ as we know it. They compiled the very first versions of C++, which was vastly different. ;)

Comment: As far as I know a `'processor'` takes all templates and replaces them by instantiations. So if CallMethod<int>(2, 3) is called, the declaration of CallMethod(Template t1, Template t2) is replaced by CallMethod(int t1, int t2). **After** `'processor'` removes templated code, the further C++ compiler runs. So couldn't one say that `'processor'` **is** a pre-processor? Cause apart from textual replacement I don't see anything else the `'processor'` needs to do.