# How can I see all instantiations created by this template code?

Tags: c++, templates, instance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Template Metaprogramming - Is it possible to output the generated code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219007/c-template-metaprogramming-is-it-possible-to-output-the-generated-code)

How can I see all the instantiations that occur after compiling the template in my C++ code? For example, after compling this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class a_type> class TemplateClass {
    a_type m_one ;
    a_type m_two ;
};

int main (){
    TemplateClass<int> intClass ;
    TemplateClass<char> charClass ;

}
```

I want to see a C++ file with class:

```
template <int> class TemplateClass {
    int m_one ;
    int m_two ;
};
```

and same class with `char`. I prefer suggestions in Eclipse or Visual Studio.

Comment: For what purposes do you need to see this?

Comment: @Avi : to see what happens in recursion build of template

Comment: I sometimes used gdb's autocompletion to list classes beginning with 'TemplateClass<' for this, but it worked only half the time.

Comment: @Avi : thanks ... you can vote to close this post .

Comment: That option isn't appearing for me :|

Comment: It is a trick I am using: just temporarily put some syntax error in your template- compiler in error messages will tell you what cannot be instantiated.