# C++ Template tracker

Tags: c++, templates

Eee... I don't even know if the name I am calling this is correct or not... but I am wondering if there is a template tracker for C++ out there somewhere. The functionality of it would be similar to the GCC compilers' `-E` switch (which expands all the macros), the only difference is that it would show the same thing for templates, such as which classes have been created, together with partial specializations, source code, which templated method are called, template parameter deduction, etc...

Comment: And allow normal people to debug template errors? We'd all be out of a job in no time.

Comment: @KerrekSB Hahaha :D Then maybe I should delete this question :P

Comment: @KerrekSB: _Normal_ what normal? Aren't we all normal? :)

Comment: A few related questions http://stackoverflow.com/q/1219007/19093 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/4448094/19093

Comment: I could imagine such could be achieved with a LLVM/CLang frontend plugin.

Answer (score 2):

There is [Templight](http://plc.inf.elte.hu/templight/), which makes it possible to trace template instantiations.

Answer (score 0):

Template tracking needs human expertise. A clue could be replace all template types with some possible concrete types and check through stepping through / debugging, once you are convinced, get into the generic version using template.