# C++ template metaprogramming for argument dispatch

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I'm reading the source code of [spconv](https://github.com/traveller59/spconv), a sparse convolution library wrote by c++ (and cuda), in the source code I found a complicate template usage, and I summarize it as a minimum working example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

template<class... T>
struct mp_list {
};

template<class T, T... I> using mp_list_c = mp_list<std::integral_constant<T, I>...>;

template<class... Ts, class F>
constexpr F mp_for_each_impl(mp_list<Ts...>, F &&f) {
    return (void) (std::initializer_list<int>{(f(Ts()), 0)...}), std::forward<F>(f);
}

template<class A, template<class...> class B>
struct mp_rename_impl {
};

template<template<class...> class A, class... T,
        template<class...> class B>
struct mp_rename_impl<A<T...>, B> {
    using type = B<T...>;
};

template<class A, template<class...> class B> using mp_rename = typename mp_rename_impl<A, B>::type;

template<class L, class F>
constexpr F mp_for_each(F &&f) {
    return mp_for_each_impl(mp_rename<L, mp_list>(), std::forward<F>(f));
}

template<int... Is, typename F>
bool dispatch_int_noexcept(int idx, F &&f) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(Is) > 0, "you need to provide at least one candidate");
    bool notFound = true;
    mp_for_each<mp_list_c<int, Is...>>([=, &notFound, &f, &idx](auto I) {
        if (decltype(I)::value == idx && notFound) {
            std::forward<F>(f)(I);
            notFound = false;
        }
    });
    return !notFound;
}

template<int ... Is, typename F>
void dispatch_int(int idx, F &&f) {
    if (!dispatch_int_noexcept<Is...>(idx, std::forward<F>(f))) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        mp_for_each<mp_list_c<int, Is...>>([=, &ss](auto I) { ss << decltype(I)::value << " "; });
        std::cout << "unknown value " << idx << ", available: " << ss.str() << std::endl;
    }
}


int main() {

    int ndim;
    std::cin >> ndim;
    dispatch_int<2, 3, 4>(ndim, [&](auto I) {
        constexpr int NDim = decltype(I)::value;
        std::cout << "using ndim= " << NDim << std::endl;
        // blablabla ... ...
    });

    return 0;
}
```

In `main()`, the function `dispatch_int<2, 3, 4>(ndim, [&](auto I) {})`reveives an argument `ndim`, and checks if `ndim` is in a predefined list `<2, 3, 4>`, if it is, then execute the following code compiled with the specific `ndim`.

However, I can't understand how this works, the templates defined above are really confusing. After a lot of searching, I guess it is a kind of template metaprogramming to dispatch argument, but still can't figure out the details, could someone explain how the above code works?

Comment: It's unclear what part of it you don't understand. You posted around 50 lines of code, you can't expect us to explain every one of them in detail. Please point specific code snippets .

Comment: Possibly use a template preprocessor tool such as the one suggested here?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139793/c-template-preprocessor-tool

Comment: I believe you can be frustrated by reading such kind of code. But there is no other way than learning template syntax and semantic. It is not as hard as it looks on the first view! Some details like "which instance fits best" or type deduction can be hard, but that is not the problem in the code posted here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the first part, (minus useless part)

```
// list of type
template<class... T>
struct mp_list {
};

// list of type, which are integral_constant
// so we can see it like a list of constexpr T
// since we can use ::value on each type 
template<class T, T... I> using mp_list_c = mp_list<std::integral_constant<T, I>...>;

template<class... Ts, class F>
constexpr void mp_for_each_impl(mp_list<Ts...>, F &&f) {
     // old school 
      (void) (std::initializer_list<int>{(f(Ts()), 0)...});
    //C++17 : 
    // (f(Ts()),...); // see : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold
    // it call f(x) for each x in Ts
}

template<class L, class F>
constexpr void mp_for_each(F &&f) {
    // mp_for_each_impl is needed to get the template list out of "L"
     mp_for_each_impl(L{}, std::forward<F>(f));
}
```

Note about "the useless part" :

```
template<class... Ts, class F>
constexpr F mp_for_each_impl(mp_list<Ts...>, F &&f) {
    return (void) (std::initializer_list<int>{(f(Ts()), 0)...}), std::forward<F>(f);
}
```

Since `for_each` doesn't need to return anything, it can return the function, may be it can be usefull in some case. And it mimics https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each

```
template<class A, template<class...> class B>
struct mp_rename_impl {
};

template<template<class...> class A, class... T,
        template<class...> class B>
struct mp_rename_impl<A<T...>, B> {
    using type = B<T...>;
};

template<class A, template<class...> class B> using mp_rename = typename mp_rename_impl<A, B>::type;
```

AFAIU, `mp_rename` is use to be generic, since `mp_for_each_impl` use `mp_list` the rename is used to convert "any type with a variadic template" into `mp_list`.

Then in :

```
template<int ... Is, typename F>
void dispatch_int(int idx, F &&f) {
    if (!dispatch_int_noexcept<Is...>(idx, std::forward<F>(f))) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        mp_for_each<mp_list_c<int, Is...>>([=, &ss](auto I) { ss << decltype(I)::value << " "; });
        std::cout << "unknown value " << idx << ", available: " << ss.str() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

the `dispatch_int_noexcept<Is...>(idx, std::forward<F>(f))`  do the work and the rest is for the error message.

then :

```
template<int... Is, typename F>
bool dispatch_int_noexcept(int idx, F &&f) {
    // just a check
    static_assert(sizeof...(Is) > 0, "you need to provide at least one candidate");
    bool notFound = true;
    mp_for_each<mp_list_c<int, Is...>>([=, &notFound, &f, &idx](auto I) {
        // look if the 'ndim' match one of the ints of dispatch_int<2, 3, 4>
        // note they are now std::integral_constant, so ::value
        if (decltype(I)::value == idx && notFound) {
            // found : call the early lambda with the integral_constant
            // that why you do the 'constexpr int NDim = decltype(I)::value;'
            std::forward<F>(f)(I);
            notFound = false;
        }
    });
    return !notFound;
}
```

Tell me if it helps

Comment: Me not! I can't see any line of explanation...

Comment: the explanation is in the comment. I didn't go into `mp_for_each`, it does what the name imply

Comment: The TO asked for explanation how the variadic template magic works...your explanation is very very top level

Comment: Really appreciate your answer! I realize that the biggest problem is I'm not familiar with template syntax, I will learn more about templates, and update the question soon.

Comment: I have add and explanation of the core code, removing the useless return and rename

Comment: Thank you very much! it really helps a lot!

Comment: @rhaport better ?

Comment: @Klaus does the explanation is good for you ? (sry can't add 2 @ in the same comment)